# Emacs install folder vs .emacs.d vs .emacs/.emacs~ confusion [Windows 10]

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows

I've recently run into complications regarding elpy and setting up virtual environments (see other questions) which have brought me back to a more fundamental issue that I must resolve before I continue integrating python functionality into emacs.

**Details:**

1. My HOME environment variable is located in `c:\users\robby parliament`
2. My root emacs install folder is located in `c:\users\robby parliament\documents`
3. The `.emacs` and `.emacs~` *files* are also located in `c:\users\robby parliament`
4. The .emacs.d *folder* is also located in `c:\users\robby parliament` and contains the following items:

```
> - c:\users\robby parliament
> --- .emacs.d
> ----- auto-save-list
> ----- elpa
> ----- elpy
> ----- snippets
> ----- url
```

**Questions:**

1. When I move the `.emacs` and `.emacs~` files into the `.emacs.d` folder I lose my theme (dracula), why is this so?
2. In response to the above question I figured I must change the HOME environment variable to `c:\users\robby parliament.emacs.d, so when I do that I get the following warning/error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘c:/Users/Robby Parliament/.emacs.d/.emacs’:

Symbol's function definition is void: elpy-enable

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

3. Then when I move the `.emacs` and `.emacs~` files *into* the `.emacs.d` subfolder within `c:\users\robby parliament\.emacs.d` the warning is now gone yet the theme is still gone. I've watched LigerLearn's tutorial on setting up emacs and the customization of the file paths several times but I feel like I'm still not understanding a fundamental concept which is bringing me all these warnings and errors. What am I doing wrong?

Also, this is within my `.emacs` file:

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(ansi-color-names-vector
   ["black" "red3" "ForestGreen" "yellow3" "blue" "magenta3" "DeepSkyBlue" "gray50"])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (dracula)))
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("b46ee2c193e350d07529fcd50948ca54ad3b38446dcbd9b28d0378792db5c088" default)))
 '(display-line-numbers t)
 '(package-archives
   (quote
    (("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
     ("melpa" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (flymake elpy dracula-theme)))
 '(ring-bell-function (quote ignore))
 '(visible-bell nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
'(setq visible-bell 1)
(elpy-enable)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c k") 'yas-expand)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c o") 'iedit-mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you move `.emacs` to `emacs.d`, Emacs just can't find it. It must reside in the `HOME` directory. You can move it to `emacs.d` but you have to rename it. You can see the pertinent Emacs manual section "The Emacs Initialization File".
2. When you change the `HOME` directory, Emacs can't find the `emacs.d` directory, which is referenced by the variable `user-emacs-directory`, with a default value of "~/.emacs.d/".
3. I don't know. But you should not be doing that anyway.

Why are you moving `.emacs` into `.emacs.d`? It doesn't belong there, but in your `HOME`. When you point `HOME` to `emacs.d`, your are messing the setup of your packages.

If you really need to move `.emacs` into `emacs.d` you can do so by renaming it to `init.el`. It is in the manual section "The Emacs Initialization File".

Comment: The only question that stands now is that since i have both a .emacs and .emacs~ file, which one do I rename and which one do I get rid of?

Comment: @katsoop: The `~` is a backup file that automatically gets created when you save a file in emacs. So you only need the `.emacs` file. Get rid of the one with the `~`.

Comment: @minibuffer Awesome - now I understand. Got rid of the one with the `~` and changed the name to init.el and moved it to the `.emacs.d` folder and everything as far as theme and elpy work for the most part. I just have one issue left regarding why the flymake syntax checker isn't working anymore. Should I post another question?